# Button image looks with inverted colors

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton, uiimage

I have a button with an image that I set like this

```
    playPauseAudioBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"icon-play-video"), forState: .Normal)
```

But looks with inverted colors, I mean: the white part of the button is black and the black part is white

**UPDATE**

Button type is Custom

**UPDATE 2**

If I set the image using the inspector it looks good. But when I modify it by code looks bad again.

**UPDATE 3**

I tried this, but it doesn't works:

```
playPauseAudioBtn.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "icon-play-video")
```

**UPDATE 4**

Here's an example:

[Before, it looks correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsjoa.png)

[After, it doesn't looks correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFbPF.png)

Comment: what are the other properties set to playPauseBtn.

Comment: Set the same image for all UIControlStates of UIbutton.

Comment: @Vurtne can you please post a answer how to resolve your problem.

Comment: @MinuMaster done about update the answer and put an image with all properties hahaha. Some ppl told me about change the type button to custom, but it don't works for me.

Comment: Are you using an Asset Catalog for you images?

Comment: @CarienvanZyl yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an Asset Catalog for your images, ensure that the **Render As** property is not set to *Template Image*.

[image]

Comment: **Render as** property is set to Default